# Can't setup Exchange account in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-2019

I'm trying to add a new account to Outlook but the wizard gives me an error:

> Log onto Exchange ActiveSync Mail server (EAS): The server cannot be found. The username or password you entered isn't working.

I checked the settings and I am able to login to OWA without problems.
Existing accounts are not affected and work fine in Outlook.

I can see no apparent problems in my Exchange server, but I also don't know where to look regarding this problem.
I find it also curious that the error message mentions that it can't find the server as well as wrong credentials.

I already did a repair installation of Exchange CU12 last night without any effect.

I also tried the [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/) to test Exchange ActiveSync.
The test passed, with a warning that my LE certificate may only work with a Root Certificate Update.

I had to manually provide the server name, as there seems to be some problem with autodiscover. I get a 403 when accessing https://autodiscover.:443/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml with the Analyzer, but it works in my browser. I would like to solve that problem as well (if it is not the root cause).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs because Outlook doesn't support connections to a server that's running Exchange Server by using the EAS protocol.
To resolve this problem, connect to Exchange by using the standard Exchange connection settings.

1. Select File > Add Account.
2. Enter your email address and click Connect.
3. If prompted, enter your password again, then select OK > Finish to start using your email account in Outlook.

Refer to: [Outlook doesn't support connections to Exchange by using ActiveSync and error: Log onto Exchange ActiveSync mail server (EAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/profiles-and-accounts/outlook-cannot-use-activesync-connect-exchange)

[Add an email account to Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b?ocmsassetid=ha102823161&correlationid=778d1d8d-9ac2-449b-9624-1268559fa794&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly this way. I really wonder how Microsoft can ship something with that kind of stupid roadblock.